# Old picture appears on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an Image on my webpage with `ImageUrl="~/global1/images/mypic.gif".`

I replaced the picture in the directory with another file of the same name, but the old one still appears when I load the page.

Even when I delete the file completely, the old picture still appears.

Why does it happen?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: what RB said, browsers like to cache things. To prevent this use Private Browsing in your browser.

Comment: Browser cache as said by RB. Try pressing **Ctrl + F5** for page refresh.

Comment: It happens with different browsers and different computers

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Clear Browser History

**Step 2:** Clean and Rebuild your Project.

**Step 3:** Now start the Application.

if still the problem appears restart the `Visual Studio IDE`.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear browser history first then check.

1. Check same thing in another browser
2. Clear browser cache
3. Re run the application

[This](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141) link describes how to clear browser history.

Answer (score 0):

Very often rebuilding/recompiling does the trick.

If not: Citing from another question "[Old picture appears on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808889/old-picture-appears-on-web-page)":

> Try adding a cachebreaker at the end of the url:
>
> ```
> newImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
> ```
>
> This will append the current timestamp automatically when you are
>   creating the image, and it will make the browser look again for the
>   image instead of retrieving the one in the cache.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't really want to do this unless the image absolutely has to be dynamic (i.e. the image is changing several times a day by design). Otherwise you will lose all the benefits of caching (which can be very important if serving image files as these tend to be large).

Comment: If your application is in development and you need to change the images from time to time, this is a good option. However, I have to agree with you that this solution is not applicable for final products where the image will be static.

Comment: I disagree - modern browsers (e.g. Chrome, IE 10+) have plenty of options in their developer tools to disable caching for specific domains, which I think is the correct approach. You want the development code to look as much like the production code as possible! However, this is a useful trick for images that do change frequently (e.g. an image that displays the current weather).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: at the end of picture add random number or use php uniqid function to break cache.

```
<img src="path/image.jpg?<?php echo uniqid(); ?>">
```